# More efficient way of deleting rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that deletes rows that are not in a specified list of row numbers that are to be kept. It functions as intended.

```
 For lRow = numRowsInBBS To 1 Step -1

    lMatch = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    lMatch = Application.Match(lRow, ws.Range("AE4:AE" & numRows).Value, 0&)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CBool(lMatch) Then
      wsImport.Cells(lRow, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

However, this takes a monumental amount of time. To do this on 150 rows takes a couple of minutes of processing. I have documents that could be 1000s of rows long.

Essentially I want to delete all rows on a specified sheet EXCEPT for the row numbers specified in `AE4:AE??` (This is calculated by numRows) on a different sheet.

The data range is not contiguous, `AE4:AE??` could list numbers 3,4,5,33,66,101,110 as rows to keep. All other rows are to be deleted.

Is there a better way of achieving my goal here?

I hear autofilter is much faster, but don't see how I can apply it here as I am not matching a string or any content in the cells, simply the row numbers.

EDIT:
As per suggestion, I have tried the autofilter way:

```
Dim rowsToKeep() As Variant: rowsToKeep = ws.Range("AE4:AE" & numRows)
Dim allRows As Range: Set allRows = Range("ZZ1:ZZ" & numRowsInBBS)

With wsImport
.Range(allRows.Address).Formula = "=row()"
.Range(allRows.Address).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=rowsToKeep, Operator:=xlFilterValues
.Range(allRows.Address).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
.Range(allRows.Address).AutoFilter Field:=1
End With
```

I am trying to:
Set the data in the range `AE4:AE??` as the data for an array -
Then use ZZ as a helper column containing row numbers -
Then filter out the rows I want to keep -
Then delete all visible rows -
Then show the rows that were filtered

However, the filter is hiding everything, which suggests to me there is something wrong with `rowsToKeep`, and yes `AE4:AE??` on the other sheet does contain values.

Comment: What have you tried with the AutoFilter approach so far (Yes, it is much faster)? Hint: You could just add a helper column and fill that with "`=row()`" of course and apply the autofilter there...

Comment: Have you tried reading the whole data set into an array, then removing what you dont need from the array, then outputting the array?

Comment: @RikSportel I have added an edit with an attempt at the AutoFilter way, but it is not quite working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this (**Untested**)

Deleting rows in a loop will always be slower. What the below code does is that it stores the rows that needs to be deleted in a range object and then deletes them at the end of the loop in One go.

```
Dim delRng As Range

For lRow = 1 To numRowsInBBS
    On Error Resume Next
    lMatch = Application.Match(lRow, ws.Range("AE4:AE" & numRows).Value, 0&)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CBool(lMatch) Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = wsImport.Rows(lRow)
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, wsImport.Rows(lRow))
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete
```

Using `CountIf` (**Untested**)

```
Dim delRng As Range

For lrow = 1 To numRowsInBBS
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("AE4:AE" & numRows), lrow) > 0 Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = wsImport.Rows(lrow)
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, wsImport.Rows(lrow))
        End If
    End If
Next

If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.Delete
```

Comment: `Invalid Procedure call or argument` on line `Set delRng = Union(delRng, wsImport.Rows(lRow))`

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. Fixed it. Please try it now

Comment: It only seems to delete the first "zone" of rows, is the only way i can describe it. Like in my original post, 3,4,5 would be deleted but 33,66, 101,110 would still be present

Comment: you tested both methods?

Comment: Ignore that, was still half asleep. What I was trying to say was it appears to get rid of rows up to the first "number to keep" then keeps everything after that. Will give the 2nd method a go now and let you know.

Comment: 2nd way didn't delete anything unfortunately

Comment: This is strange. The code should work... What values do you have in `"AE4:AE" & numRows`

Comment: `AE4:AE997` so numRows is 997 in this case. The values in `AE4:AE997` look like this - `0,0,0,4,5,6,0,0,0,10,11,12,0,0,15` and so on. Basically where there is a number `>0` that is a row to be kept, the rest deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147154/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-aurelius).